# Glassmapper SitecoreContext Unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sitecore, glass-mapper

I'm creating a unit test using Xunit to test a method that calls for the SitecoreContext and is always returning null.

I am using FakeDB for the site context.

This is the method to unit test:

```
public static Model GetModelData(object owner)
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new SitecoreContext())
        {
            string homePath = Sitecore.Context.Site.ContentStartPath;
            Model = context.GetItem<Model>(string.Format("{0}/Configuration/Model", homePath));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("GetModelData() Exception: " + ex.InnerException, owner);
    }
    return backToTop;
}
```

I've created a fake SiteContext using FakeDb and called for the method. Here is what I've tried:

```
    var fakeSite = new Sitecore.FakeDb.Sites.FakeSiteContext(new Sitecore.Collections.StringDictionary
    {
        { "name", "fakesite" }, { "database", "master" }, { "rootPath", "/sitecore/content/home" }
    });
    using (new Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextSwitcher(fakeSite))
    {       
        var result = SomeClass.GetModelData(this);
        result.Should().NotBeNull();
    }
```

When debugging, I get that the var context is returning null. Is there a way to like mock the Glassmapper SitecoreContext? or is this not possible because I'm introducing a new SitecoreContext from the method?

Answer (score 4):

What exactly are you testing here? FakeDB? Sitecore? Looks like the unit test is designed to exercise Glass and nothing more.  There's no actual logic being exercised, no assumptions being documented.

Further, it's not surprising that you're having difficulty testing this as there's so many dependencies in just 5 lines of code. Unit testing is really much easier when you're focussing your tests on just **your** code. There's no need to write unit tests for Sitecore, Glass and FakeDB - that's not your job. You need to restructure this code so that dependencies (Glass context, the start path, and the diagnostics logger) are inputs to the processing - arguments to your `ctor` normally.  That way you can control the parameters of the code under test, rather than relying on implicit behaviour you've inherited through the use of the statics.  No doubt there is code buried within Glass that relies on the HttpContext that you have not mocked out properly, which is why it isn't working.  Removing the calls to static members and instead passing these values in to your code will allow you to easily mock them out when the code is under test, and you won't have these sorts of problems at all.

I strongly suggest you rethink your unit test strategy entirely though, because the test *as written above* in a waste of energy.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap you code in using of Db instance.

Something like that:

```
[TestCase]
public void FooTest()
{
    using (var db = new Db { })
    {
        var fakeSite = new Sitecore.FakeDb.Sites.FakeSiteContext(new Sitecore.Collections.StringDictionary
        {
            { "name", "website" }, { "database", "web" }
        });
        using (new Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextSwitcher(fakeSite))
        {
            Sitecore.Context.Site.Name.Should().Be("website");
            Sitecore.Context.Site.Database.Name.Should().Be("web");
        }
    }
}
```